# vue is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to build a simple app in vue and I'm getting an error. My onScroll function behaves as expected, but my sayHello function returns an error when I click my button component

> Property or method "sayHello" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option. (found in component )

```
Vue.component('test-item', {
    template: '<div><button v-on:click="sayHello()">Hello</button></div>'
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        header: {
            brightness: 100
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sayHello: function() {
            console.log('Hello');
        },
        onScroll: function () {
            this.header.brightness = (100 - this.$el.scrollTop / 8);
        }
    }
});
```

I feel like the answer is really obvious but I've tried searching and haven't come up with anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `sayHello` isn't a method of `test-item`. It's a method of `app`.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz, that did it.

I did read that here: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html that each component is contained in its own isolated scope.

So, my component doesn't inherit the methods that I give to the root Vue instance?

Comment: Gotcha. 

Very interesting, thanks again. I'll mark your answer as correct, cheers.

Comment: It takes a bit of getting used to, but you'll love it as you architect large apps in Vue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

But for a few specific circumstances (mainly `props`) each component is completely isolated from each other. Separate data, variables, functions, etc. This includes their methods.

Thus, `test-item` has no `sayHello` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the warning by using **`.mount('#app')`** after the Vue instance rather than the **`el`** *attribute*.

Check the snippet below;

```
var app = new Vue({
    data: {
        header: {
            brightness: 100
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sayHello: function() {
            console.log('Hello');
        },
        onScroll: function () {
            this.header.brightness = (100 - this.$el.scrollTop / 8);
        }
    }
}).mount('#app');
```

***Please note; the following might not be necessary but did it along the way trying to solve the same issue: [Laravel Elixir Vue 2](https://github.com/vuejs/laravel-elixir-vue-2) project.***